# ls or dir - limit the number of file name returns

Tags: cygwin, ls, dir

Is there a way to limit the number of filenames to be returned using the ls or dir command? I'm on a windows machine with cygwin, so either command will do.

I have a directory with over 1 million docs that I need to batch out into subfolders. I'm looking to write a simple script that would list the first 20,000 or so, move them to a subfolder, then repeat on the next 20,000. I would expect ls or dir to have an option to list only a certain number of files, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

My other option is to print the filenames out to a text file and parse that to make the moves. It seems like there should be a simpler solution though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using cygwin, you should be able to use the head command, like this:

```
ls | head -20000
```

to list the first 20 thousand.

If you want to move the batch in 1 command line, something like this should work:

```
ls | head -20000 | xargs -I {} mv {} subdir
```

(where subdir is the subdir you want to move the files to).

Run this first (with the echo command) to verify it will work before running the actual move:

```
ls | head -20000 | xargs -I {} echo mv {} subdir
```

Just be careful though, since you are moving files into a subdir, because the "ls" command will probably pick up your subdirs as well.

If they are all txt files, you could do something like this:

```
ls | grep txt$ | head -20000 | xargs -I {} mv {} subdir
```

to get files that end in txt

Answer (score 2):

Or you might want to combine `head` and `tail` to fetch entries out of the middle:

Example data:

```
banana
cherry
apple
orange
plum
strawberry
redcurrant
```

Now let's skip 2 entries and fetch the following 2 ones:

```
cat fruit.txt | head -n 4 | tail -n 2
```

That will give you:

```
apple
orange
```

So `head -n 4` will return the first 4 entries (*banana* to *orange*) and the following `tail -n 2` will get the last 2 ones out of that **previous result** (*apple* to *orange*) and not out of the original file.